# ¿Qué es la gramática de verse + gerundio?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, sintaxis, locuciones, gerundio

He visto frases como "váyanse imaginando la foto" pero no entiendo la diferencia entre decir eso y decir "imagínense la foto."

He buscado si hay una forma gramática de usar verse con gerundio pero no encontré nada.

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "váyanse imaginando" e "imagínense"?

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "me veo imaginando" e "imagino"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En realidad sería la forma "ir + gerundio" (no ver/verse, aunque también. Mira la [conjugación del verbo ir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=M5ucdgy), que tiene formas "vaya_" en algunos tiempos verbales, con especial interés para esta pregunta del imperativo: *vaya usted/vayan ustedes*) que describe una acción que se realiza de forma gradual o por etapas, pero de manera continua.

El significado del verbo ir (o ver) se completa, modifica o aclara por medio del gerundio. Un aspecto clave es que los resultados de la acción se manifiestan poco a poco y/o de forma continuada. Por ejemplo:

> Déjalo fuera del congelador para que **vaya descongelándose**

¿Qué diferencia hay entre "váyanse imaginando" e "imagínense"? Pues una diferencia sutil, la de una acción progresiva en el primer caso. Por ejemplo

> **Vete haciendo a la idea** de que no podrás comprar eso si no ahorras <sub>start getting used to the idea</sub>

Indica "piensa en esto, reflexiona, considera". Algo así como si dieras tiempo al interlocutor para entender el concepto.

> **Hazte a la idea** de que no podrás comprar eso si no ahorras <sub>get used to the idea</sub>

Implica inmediatez. Las cosas son así y punto. No le des más vueltas, que no hay nada que entender.

De igual manera "váyanse imaginando" implica "imagine de forma progresiva esto" (a medida que mi argumento avanza y le doy más detalles, por ejemplo).

¿Qué diferencia hay entre "me veo imaginando" e "imagino"? De igual manera, la primera indica una acción continua. Ese "me veo imaginando" no es más que un "me imagino (a mi mismo) imaginando", es decir, realizando una acción progresiva y continuada.

Otro ejemplo:

> Mi relación con esta persona va muy bien. **Me veo casado** dentro de una año.

Esto significa: me imagino que en el futuro estaré casado.

> Mi relación con esta persona va muy bien. **Me veo casándome** dentro de una año.

Esto significa: me imagino realizando la acción de casarme en el futuro. No necesariamente la ceremonia en sí, sino el proceso más general que lleva desde la decisón de contraer matrimonio hasta su realización.

Comment: Sí, me equivoqué con la conyugación. Excelente respuesta. ¡Gracias, Diego!